# Specify multifield on an array item - elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

How do I specify a multifield index mapping that targets a property inside an array?

For example

```
 Document
 --------
 ID: 1
 Title: Some title goes here
 Content: Some content goes here
 SubDocuments:[{"Title:"Some title"},{"Title:"Some title"}]
```

How can I specify an index mapping that targets Title inside SubDocuments to have touched and untouched variations?

Thanks

Comment: See if this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30710988/elastic-search-multi-value-field-aggregation

Answer (score 0):

[Arrays](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-array-type.html) are supported out of the box by Elasticsearch and they don't need a specific mapping. You simply need to map the `SubDocuments` field as an `object` (or `nested` object) and then the `Title` field as a multi-field in that object.

```
{
    "your_type" : {
        "properties" : {
            "ID" : {"type" : "long"},
            "Title" : {"type" : "string"},
            "Content" : {"type" : "string"},
            "SubDocuments" : {
                "properties" : {
                    "Title" : {
                        "type" : "string",
                        "fields": {
                            "raw": {
                                "type" : "string",
                                "index" : "not_analyzed",
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is worth noting that if you envision to add other fields to `SubDocuments` and you need to query on those `SubDocuments` fields, it might be wiser to map `SubDocuments` as [`nested` type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html), like this:

```
{
    "your_type" : {
        "properties" : {
            "ID" : {"type" : "long"},
            "Title" : {"type" : "string"},
            "Content" : {"type" : "string"},
            "SubDocuments" : {
                "type": "nested",           <---- add this
                "properties" : {
                    "Title" : {
                        "type" : "string",
                        "fields": {
                            "raw": {
                                "type" : "string",
                                "index" : "not_analyzed",
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your documents, `SubDocuments.Title` will be the field containing the analyzed variation and `SubDocuments.Title.raw` will be another field containing the exact and non-analyzed string value.